# Entity Framwork adding to database where I decide the foreign key ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Simplified I have an `Employee` class and a `Role` class, which looks like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now comes the problem.

Let's say that I know that ID 3 in Role is "Manager".

I want to add a new employee to the database with `RoleID = 3`, so he will be a manager.

When I add the employee to the database, it's like Entity Framework just skips reading `RoleID`.

Instead of referring to the already existing role with ID 3, it just makes a new role with the name, manager and with ID 4 in the database.

I'm not sure if I made myself clear enough, but I hope some of you clever guys can help me

The full code

First part is some method in a SetUp class

```
        var db = new EmployeeRepository(new DataBaseContext());

        var role = new DBEntities.Role { Name = "Employee" };
        var employee = new DBEntities.Employee
        {
            Name = "Adam"
            Role = role
        };
        db.Create(employee);
```

EmployeeRepository:

```
         private readonly DataBaseContext _context;

         public EmployeeRepository(DataBaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

         public void Create(Employee employee)
    {
        var roleId = from r in _context.Roles
            where r.Name == employee.Role.Name
            select r.ID; 
        employee.RoleID = roleId.First();
        employee.Role.ID = roleId.First();

        _context.Employees.Add(employee);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Post the code, which adds an employee.

Comment: **Show us the code!** Show us how you create a new employee that should become a manager!

Comment: Are you setting the `Role` property to a new `Role` as well as the `RoleID == 3`? This will cause the behaviour you describe because you are setting `Role` to a new entity that is not being tracked to will be added to the databse and associated with your `Employee`. If you set `RoleID == 3` alone, it should not do this.

Comment: I've added some more code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

private readonly DataBaseContext _context;

```
     public EmployeeRepository(DataBaseContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

     public void Create(Employee employee)
{
    var roles = from r in _context.Roles
        where r.Name == employee.Role.Name
        select r; 
    employee.Role = roles.First();

    _context.Employees.Add(employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or, you can just set employee.RoleId and not set Employee.Role:

```
public void Create(Employee employee)
{
    var roleIds = from r in _context.Roles
        where r.Name == employee.Role.Name
        select r.ID; 
    employee.RoleId = roleIds.First();
    employee.Role = null;

    _context.Employees.Add(employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That worked...I cant belive i didnt think of that, when i tried both setting the RoleID and Role.ID, but not just the whole Role..
Thank you very much.